# Array of Circles put on stage on mouse event

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransitionBuilder;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransitionBuilder;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransitionBuilder;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Temp4 extends Application {
    private Animation animation;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
    final Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    //Make stage transparent 
    //primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300);
    //rect.setFill(Color.RED);

    // Adding circles at Mouse Click 
    scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){    

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent me){
             Group listOfCircles = new Group();
             for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
                 Circle circle = new Circle(50*Math.random());
                 Color c = new Color(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1.0);
                 circle.setFill(c);
                 listOfCircles.getChildren().add(circle);
                 }
                 for (Node circle : listOfCircles.getChildren()){
                     timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                             new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, 
                             new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(),800),
                             new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty(),500)
                             ), 
                             new KeyFrame(new Duration(2000), 
                             new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(),me.getSceneX()+10),
                             new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty(),me.getSceneY()+10)
                             ));                                   
              }
              timeline.play();
              primaryStage.show();   

            }

          });       


    //scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {        
      //                      public void handle(MouseEvent me2){
        //                    scene.getChildren().clear();
          //          }  
   // });





    //public double getSampleWidth() { return 400; }

//    public double getSampleHeight() { return 150; }


    //root.getChildren().add();
    //primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    //primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    //primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    }
}
```

I tried to put circles at the same place where I clicked on stage via  a mouse event, Netbeans keeps running forever or throws an exception.

I don't have a package class created. I am new to javafx. If a package class mandatory ??

Comment: Putting classes in a package is not mandatory but is strongly recommended; for an application like this which looks like you are just experimenting it is fine to use the "default package".

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong in your code.

When the mouse is clicked, you create a Group (which you call "listOfCircles") containing five circles, but at no point do you make it part of your scene. You need to put it in the Scene Graph somehow: calling something like

```
root.getChildren().add(listOfCircles);
```

before you start the animation will work.

You also create the Scene, with a root node ("root"), but you never put the scene in a window ("stage" in JavaFX terminology) or show the window.
Uncomment the lines

```
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
```

and

```
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
```

Maybe it is worth starting with something simpler: maybe the [Hello World](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm) from the [standard tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm), and experiment with the code there to understand what each line does.